# Clearing Asp.net Bin folder before deploying code using TeamCity

Tags: asp.net, teamcity, web-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am a newbie to **TeamCity** and **Octopus Deploy**.

My project has many branches that uses different version of 3rd party dlls. The problem i am facing is when i am switching branches in TeamCity and build the code it deploys (using Octopus Deploy) the code successfully but it doesn't clear the target folder.

Like the Bin folder holds all the dll required by the project so when i switch branches and build using TeamCity and deployed using Octopus Deploy the previous dll are not removed and the application shows following error due to existence of same class in multiple dlls

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of ways to do this. It really depends on how you are versioning and deploying your code from TeamCity to Octopus. If you are using NuGet pacakges and providing a version for each package, then having Octopus trigger a deployment based on the new package version, you will have a new directory for each deployment, and you won't have this problem at all. That being said, here are a couple of ways to fix this in your current workflow.

1. Use a Powershell script as the first step in your deployment, and have that  script clean the deployment directory.
2. Use a "Custom Installation Directory" and set the "Purge this directory before installation" flag.

To enable the "Custom Installation Directory," click on "Enable features," on the bottom of your deployment step, and check "Custom installation directory"
[image: Enable Features Screenshot]

Then configure your directory path and check the "Purge this directory before installation" option.
[image]